# MAUI: Label.Text is not working when the label has PropertyChanged event

Tags: maui

I am trying to set the label's Text value on the `xaml.cs` file which has `PropertyChanged` event. The text value is not showing on the UI with `PropertyChanged` event. If I remove the `PropertyChanged` event the text value is showing on the UI.

**My Label:**

```
<Label 
    x:Name="selectcategory_label"
    PropertyChanged="selectcategory_label_PropertyChanged"
    Text="Select a category"
    Style="{StaticResource InvoiceUserLabelStyle}"/>
```

**Settings text like below:**

```
selectcategory_label.Text = "Books";
```

Is it a known issue?

**Update**

**@Jason and @GChapX**: I am working on a form where I have a Title (Entry), Description (Editor), Category (Label), and a Submit Button. The `Button` is in disable state and after entering all the details it will be enable. That logic I have added on `PropertyChanged` event.

```
private void selectcategory_label_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title_entry.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(description_editor.Text) && selectcategory_label.Text != "Select a category")
    {
        submit_button.IsEnabled = true;
        submit_button.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("#f3872c");
    }
    else
    {
        submit_button.IsEnabled = false;
        submit_button.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("#d5d5d5");
    }
}
```

When setting category I will check the title and descriptions are available and based on that I am enabling the button. That's all I am doing on `PropertyChanged` event.

**@Liqun Shen-MSFT**: I commented out the code in selectcategory_label_PropertyChanged event and label is working at that time and I am working in debug mode.

Comment: what is the point of having `PropertyChanged` on a `Label`?  The user cannot make any changes to the `Label`

Comment: Hard to reproduce this issue. You may comment out the code in ```selectcategory_label_PropertyChanged``` event handler to see if the label still cannot show.

Comment: Some more details maybe.What platform do you use? Release or debug?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT I have updated the question with all details.

Comment: @Jason I have updated the question with all details.

Comment: I recommend you use [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/) to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/) to achieve this.

Here is an easy example:

Suppose this is ***XAML***,

```
<StackLayout>
    <Entry x:Name="title_entry"
           Placeholder="Title"
           Text="{Binding EntryText}"/>
    <Editor x:Name="description_editor"
            Placeholder="Description"
            Text="{Binding EditorText}"/>

    <Label 
        x:Name="selectcategory_label"                  
        Text="{Binding LabelText,Mode=TwoWay}"
        Style="{StaticResource InvoiceUserLabelStyle}"
        />

    <Button x:Name="submit_button"
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"
            BackgroundColor="{Binding ButtonBackground}"
            Text="submit"/>
</StackLayout>
```

In ViewModel, decide the IsEnabled of Button when label Text changed. For viewmodel, remember to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode#viewmodels-and-property-change-notifications).

```
private string labelText = "Select a category";
public string LabelText
{
    get
    {
        return labelText;
    }
    set
    {
        labelText = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(LabelText)));
        IsButtonEnabled();
    }
}


//add your logic in this method
private void IsButtonEnabled()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EntryText) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EditorText) && LabelText != "Select a category")
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You could use CommunityToolkit.Mvvm nuget to simplify the code if you want.

Hope it helps！